# python - modify a list of strings via regex

Tags: python, regex, string, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings

```
query_var = ["VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' & EVENT_GENRE == 'ROMANCE' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1","VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Jamshedpur' & EVENT_GENRE == 'HORROR' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1"]
len(query_var)   #o/p 2
```

I want to modify this list to get

```
 query_var = ["df['VENUE_CITY_NAME'] == 'Bangalore' & df['EVENT_GENRE'] == 'ROMANCE' & df['count_EVENT_GENRE'] >= 1","df['VENUE_CITY_NAME'] == 'Jamshedpur' & df['EVENT_GENRE'] == 'HORROR' & df['count_EVENT_GENRE'] >= 1"]
```

This is my attempt:

```
for res in query_var:
    res = [x for x in re.split('[&)]',res)]
    print(res)
    res =  [x.strip() for x in res]
    print(res)
    res = [d.replace(d.split(' ', 1)[0], "df['"+d.split(' ', 1)[0]+"']") for d in res]
    print(res)
```

which produces the output:

```
 ["VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' ", " EVENT_GENRE == 'ROMANCE' ", ' count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1']
 ["VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore'", "EVENT_GENRE == 'ROMANCE'", 'count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1']
 ["df['VENUE_CITY_NAME'] == 'Bangalore'", "df['EVENT_GENRE'] == 'ROMANCE'", "df['count_EVENT_GENRE'] >= 1"]
 ["VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Jamshedpur' ", " EVENT_GENRE == 'HORROR' ", ' count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1']
 ["VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Jamshedpur'", "EVENT_GENRE == 'HORROR'", 'count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1']
 ["df['VENUE_CITY_NAME'] == 'Jamshedpur'", "df['EVENT_GENRE'] == 'HORROR'", "df['count_EVENT_GENRE'] >= 1"]
```

AS expected, but when I print `query_var` it was not changed

```
query_var
Out[47]: 
   ["VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' & EVENT_GENRE == 'ROMANCE' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1","VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Jamshedpur' & EVENT_GENRE == 'HORROR' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1"]
```

As you can see my code does not produce the desired output. Is there a better way, for example with a list comprehension?

Comment: You need to assign `res` value to `query_var` in order to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a regex/list comprehension solution:

```
>>> [re.sub('(\w+)\s*(==|>=)', r"df['\1'] \2", s) for s in query_var]
["df['VENUE_CITY_NAME'] == 'Bangalore' & df['EVENT_GENRE'] == 'ROMANCE' & df['count_EVENT_GENRE'] >= 1", "df['VENUE_CITY_NAME'] == 'Jamshedpur' & df['EVENT_GENRE'] == 'HORROR' & df['count_EVENT_GENRE'] >= 1"]
```

Adjust it as needed for more general data, i.e. permitting '<=', for example.

*edit* in response to the comment:

```
[re.sub('(\w+)(\s*(==|>=).*?)(\s*&|$)', r"(df['\1']\2)\4", s) for s in query_var]
```

Comment: @timgeb-just one more small help....i want to include () for each segment sep by & symbol...ex.["(df['VENUE_CITY_NAME'] == 'Bangalore') & (df['EVENT_GENRE'] == 'ROMANCE') & (df['count_EVENT_GENRE'] >= 1)"

Comment: as for this i can't raise one more question.i can do this after running the reg exp.but i am just not getting how to do that inside the reg exp as suggested by you...

Comment: @Satya updated, please provide the correct/full specifications in the original question next time